# Hibernate OnetoOne mapping with two lookup values

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a class which has two lookup values (one for name and one for type)

```
public class someAttr {
private Long someAttrId;
private Long projectId;

private Lookup typeLookupValue;
private Lookup nameLookupValue;

getters & setter...

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "type_lk_id", referencedColumnName = "lk_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public LookupValue getTypeLookupValue() {
    return typeLookupValue;
}

public void setTypeLookupValue(Lookup typeLookupValue) {
    this.typeLookupValue= typeLookupValue;
}

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "name_lk_id", referencedColumnName = "lk_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public LookupValue getNameLookupValue() {
    return nameLookupValue;
}

public void setNameLookupValue(Lookup nameLookupValue) {
    this.nameLookupValue= nameLookupValue;
}
```

The problem is that the same name_lk_id is shared between different someAttr object.
Every time I run it I get:
"org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found".

Can I get nameLookupValue which belongs to a specific someAttr with a projectId instead of getting multiple Lookup object with the same "lk_id"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One someAttr instance is associated to two Lookup value instances. This is not a One-To-One relationship. You need to use One-to-Many relationship for this. You can have helper methods inside your class to retrieve the approrpiate Lookup instance from the List/Set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably you two saved a huge amount of time for me (and probably a lot of my hair ;))